# react redux axios post signup request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm learning redux, I'm trying to create a registration form. When I send my form nothing happens. Can you tell me if the development of the action and the reducer and service are well done?I have the impression that no data goes into the action or maybe I'm doing something wrong with axios. I tried with FormData() for axios but still the same result. thanks in advance

action auth

```
export const registerClient = (dispatch, lastname,firstname,adress,codePostal,city,country,phone,email,password, isLoggedIn)=>{
    const data = (lastname,firstname,adress,codePostal,city,country,phone,email,password, isLoggedIn)
        dispatch({
            type: ActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: {client: data}
        })   
}
```

Reducer auth

```
export default function AuthClient (state = initialState, action){
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch (type) {
        case ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: true,
                client: payload.client
            }
    
        case ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: false,
                client: null
            }

        case ActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            console.log(payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: true,
                client: payload.client
            }

        case ActionTypes.REGISTER_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: false,
            }

        case ActionTypes.LOGOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: false,
                client: null,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Service

```
export const registerService = (lastname,firstname,adress,codePostal,city,country, navigate,phone,email,password, isLoggedIn, dispatch) =>{
    
    axios.post(API_URL_CLIENT_AUTH + "createClient",{     
        lastname,
        firstname,
        adress,
        codePostal,
        city,
        country,
        phone,
        email,
        password
})
    .then((response)=>{
        actionAuth.registerClient(lastname,firstname,adress,codePostal,city,country, 
        navigate,phone,email,password,dispatch)

        localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(response.data))
        return response
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        const errorFailRegister = error
        failRegisterClient(dispatch)
        errorAction(errorFailRegister,dispatch)
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the server's response? Did the request go through?

Comment: @timotgl the request is not passed, I receive neither error nor response

Comment: I managed to pass my request, but I get a 404 status. formData returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will rewrite your action, cause it's not well defined:

```js
export const registerClient = (lastname, firstname, address, codePostal, city, country, phone, email, password, isLoggedIn) => {
    // ** here remove the dispatch
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            client: {
                lastname,
                firstname,
                address,
                codePostal,
                city,
                country,
                phone,
                email,
                password,
                isLoggedIn,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your reducer is fine. Last change is in the service:

```js
export const registerService = (lastname, firstname, adress, codePostal, city, country, navigate, phone, email, password, isLoggedIn, dispatch) => {

    axios.post(API_URL_CLIENT_AUTH + "createClient", {
        lastname,
        firstname,
        adress,
        codePostal,
        city,
        country,
        phone,
        email,
        password
    })
        .then((response) => {
            // ** here, call the dispatch
            dispatch(actionAuth.registerClient(lastname, firstname, adress, codePostal, city, country,
                navigate, phone, email, password, dispatch))
            
            localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(response.data)) // You can do this later with a middleware, when you're ready
            // for that
            return response
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorFailRegister = error
            failRegisterClient(dispatch)
            errorAction(errorFailRegister, dispatch)
        })
}
```

So, explaining: 'dispatch' is to tell redux to run an action, so the action itself cannot call the dispatch function. You can call dispatch in the client of the redux store you are building

Comment: Thank you very much @Osmanys Fuentes-Lombá for these explanations and help. I tried as you told me, but it doesn't work. I don't get the response or the error with axios

Comment: I have a problem with the action, infact he never calls. I commented the code in the action is the registration passes anyway

Comment: You fixed as I suggested and still not working??

Comment: no the action is not broadcast, the data goes directly to the service, I put console logs in action and reducer, they are not called

Comment: I just found the problem, I had an additional parameter so the dispatch was not retrieved. everything works thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much everyone for the help it works, @Osmanys Fuentes-Lombá fix for everything redux is correct and then i fixed axios like this:

```
export const registerService = (lastname, firstname, adress, codePostal, city, country, navigate, phone, email, password, isLoggedIn, dispatch) => {

const client ={
       lastname,
       firstname,
       adress,
       codePostal,
       city,
       country,
       phone,
       email,
       password
}

   axios.post(API_URL_CLIENT_AUTH + "createClient",client)
       .then((response) => {
           // ** here, call the dispatch
           dispatch(actionAuth.registerClient(lastname, firstname, adress, codePostal, city, country,
               navigate, phone, email, password, dispatch))
           
           localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(response.data)) // You can do this later with a middleware, when you're ready
           // for that
           return response
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           const errorFailRegister = error
           failRegisterClient(dispatch)
           errorAction(errorFailRegister, dispatch)
       })
}
```